# How to block all chat requests except those with an email history?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I am constantly interrupted with chat requests from spammers, like porn operators. I would like to disable/deny all requests unless they originate from a user whom I have an email history.

Searching through [Google Talk](https://support.google.com/talk/?hl=en) help I don't see a discussion of blocking users before the chat request is made.

Is it possible to disable/deny requests unless they originate from a user whom I have an email history? If so, then how do I do it?

---

Here is the program I am referring to. The window does not have a name, and hovering over it does not provide a tooltip with the name of the program.

[image]

Here is an example of unsolicited porn requests. I've never had a contact with Kimberly or Patricia. There is absolutely no reason they should be contacting me:

[image]

Comment: Google Talk web app was shutdown some time ago. What web app are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Rubén. I added a capture of the program I am talking about. I thought it was called Google Talk. I don't know what it is called nowadays. It is docked in the GMail page in the lower left hand corner of the window.

Comment: The app name is Google Hangouts.

Comment: Related [Block or Ignore someone on Hangouts who only sends me group messages (spam)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125713/88163)

Comment: Thank @Rubén - Yeah, based on the similar question, it probably cannot be done. Another *＋1* for to Google for subjecting us to the spam.